# Java Android 2D Game - Issue with virtual borders

Tags: java, android, 2d, border

I'm a computer scientist student and I'm new to programming. To challenge myself, I decided to try my hand at creating a simple 2D android game.
The issue I'm having is related to the borders. I have a player character who can move left and right along the X-axis, although the character is not supposed to go outside of the screen. This works for the most part, but holding the button that sends your characters towards left/right will make the character go through the border.

What I have in terms of code is essentially an if statement in the update() method that checks if the x value of the player character is < 0 (for the left border) and if that statement is true then it prevents the player from clicking the left button again until the right button has been clicked (player's x value is again greater than 0).

How do I solve this? My first idea was that I could have something that checks the gamestate every 5 ms or something and if the player's x value is equal to or less than 0, then set the movement speed to 0 until the right button has been clicked, but I do not know how to implement this check.

Do you have any idea how this could be implemented or if there is a better solution? Thank you very much!

Here's the relevant code:

```
//In class GamePanel
public void update() {
    if (player.getX() <= 4) {
       player.setTooFarLeft(true);
       MOVESPEED = 0;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        final float scaleFactorX = getWidth() / (WIDTH * 1.f);
        final float scaleFactorY = getHeight() / (HEIGHT * 1.f);
        Rect right = new Rect((int) ((WIDTH * scaleFactorX) / 3 + (int) (WIDTH * scaleFactorX) / 3), 0, (int) (WIDTH * scaleFactorX), (int) (HEIGHT * scaleFactorY));
        Rect left = new Rect(0, 0, (int) (WIDTH * scaleFactorX / 3), (int) (HEIGHT * scaleFactorY));
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        //Same for right
        if (left.contains(x, y) && player.getTooFarLeft()==false) {
            if (!player.getPlaying()) {
                player.setPlaying(true);
            } else {
                player.setMovement(4);
                player.setLeft(true);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        player.setMovement(8);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make an android game without using a game engine. While this is possible, I would not recommend it for a beginner. There are plenty of great Android game engines out there that will help you with updating the world/graphics. Some of these include [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) and [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/). While they can be overwhelming to start learning, the outcome will be a better/faster game and experience that is very expandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do if player's x is less than 0, set his x cordinates to 3.

Comment: I never thought that would work when I thought about possible solutions, but it worked like a charm. Thank you for the help. :)